# hibernate reversed one-to-one

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have two classes A and B that should be in one-to-one relationship by foreign key.A has a_id as primary key and B has a_id foreign key
But i want class B to be only aware of A's identifier(i.e. there is no field of type A in class B), while A loads whole B class

I tried(A class)

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="a_id",referencedColumnName="a_id")
private B b;
```

But hibernate tries to join

```
a.a_id = b.b_id
```

instead of

```
a.a_id = b.a_id
```

Any ideas how expected behaviour can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One to one is used for an inheritance type scenario. I'm not sure you want to use one to one vs many to one for this situation. Try a many to one with a unique constraint.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="a_id") //better name would be a_fk
private B b;
```

But i have had troulbe with 1:1 relationships some year ago, in this case I used a ManyToOne as workaround:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="a_id") //better name would be a_fk
private B b;
```